# why can't we override inside a class

Tags: java, function, overriding

I am writing a code of game and I am using KeyAdapter class for keyboard Inputs but I am encountring a problem. I am extending and using function of KeyAdapter class as follows

```
class Kadapter extends KeyAdapter {
  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    //here i will write required code
  } 
}
```

When i am writing it outside all class then I am not getting any error in overriding the function key pressed
but now suppose if I define it inside any other class as shown here

```
class Arena extends JPanel {
  Player pl;

  Arena() {
    pl = new Player();
  }

  class Kadapter extends KeyAdapter {
    @Override
    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Then I am getting error in overriding the function keyPressed. can anyone tell me why. I wanted to define it inside the arena class because i will require the same instance of player class in Kadapter class. well i could pass that instance through functions. but my question here is that why can't we override the same function inside arena class.I will find any alternate solution about player problem that's not a problem but please tell me about this Override problem. I am very curious about it.

Comment: KeyPressed is different from keyPressed. Java is case-sensitive. Next time, post the exact and complete error you get: it tells exactly what and where the problem is, and reading it helps enormously. Everything becomes much easier when you read error messages. And indent your code to make it readable. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Thank you i just noticed my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define and implement inside the nested class. There should not be any issue.

So far I can see only issue is with method name as **KeyPressed** .

```
class Arena extends JPanel {
  Player pl;

  Arena() {
    pl = new Player();
  }

  class Kadapter extends KeyAdapter {
    @Override
    public void KeyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }
  }
}
```

It should be **keyPressed**

k as lower case!

Comment: Thank you guys. Just noticed I was writing 'K' in uppercase. That was my mistake. Thank you again